# Unauthorized 401 error while 'execute as me'

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization, google-oauth, google-sites

I am struggling with a web app I have deployed.  When the site permission is available to 'all with the link', as the app is set to 'execute as me', a spreadsheet is properly removed from my drive and a new file created.  If I restrict access to certain email addresses, the code no longer works.

I tried passing a token using

```
  var auth = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var header = {
    "authorization": "Bearer " + auth
  };
  var params = { 'method':'post', 'headers':header, 'muteHttpExceptions':true};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL, params);
  Logger.log(response);
```

Unfortunately the execution response is

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

A Google Doc is created with the html text on it in my drive, so I think access is available but something has changed with the permissions.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**:

It looks like the script needs me to sign in again even though I am passing an OAuth2 access token.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getOAuthToken()

The scope to Google sites is in place, so I'm not sure why I can't get the response to work properly.  It's falling down at UrlFetchApp but just passing the OAuth2 token doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: Who has access to the app? Is it set to "anyone" or "anyone, even anonymous"?

Comment: It is set to "anyone"

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can access the Web Apps with "anyone" using Manifests. Please try to do the following flow.

- On script editor of the project with the URL fetch method.

  1. View -> Show manifest file
  2. Please add the following oauthScopes to `appsscript.json`.

     - `"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]`

By this, the access token retrieved by `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` has the above scopes. After this setting, please try to run your script again. In your sceipt, you can access the Web Apps with "anyone" using `auth`.

If this didn't work, please redeploy Web Apps again. Because the latest version of scripts for Web Apps might not be reflected.

#### Reference :

- [Manifests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests)

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tanaike.  It turns out that with Google Sites, you need to specify specific feed URI to get to the attachments (when restricting permissions), rather than the download links from the site.  The scopes were already set, including the one for sites `https://sites.google.com/feeds`  but i appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help you.