# How to use url fetch in google script with credentials and authorization header

Tags: google-apps-script, fetch, credentials

I am not able to have a successful fetch with authorization, I keep getting error "401 Unauthorized" but when I try the direct url in my browser, everything is fine.
My google script code :

```
var params = { 
"headers" : {
   "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + password)
},
"followRedirects" : true,
"muteHttpExceptions" : true,
"validateHttpsCertificates" : false
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getContentText();
```

and the working direct link has the format :

```
http://username:password@myServer
```

Any ideas ?

Edited : Some details on what I try to do : I have a bitcoin miner at home, which has a web server to monitor it and I want to put the data on a google sheet like every hour. The first step is to access the server through internet and for that I configured my router with NAT and I successfuly see my miner web page by using my public IP address but it is not working with google script fetch function.  I think that the tricky part is about the authorization, because when I try to access to just the IP address, it asks me the login and password, so ok but how to give that credentials to the fetch function ? I saw that we could embbed directly in the url with the form username:password@myServer instead of just myServer. I tried it on my phone (wifi disabled) and it works great. This form is appearently not supported by fetch function, so I tried with the authorization header but I keeps getting error 401 as if my credentials are wrong

Also, here are the complete logs that is available in the web interface :
https://www.transfernow.net/ahhOQ3122020

Here is the response when using apitester.com :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="antMiner Configuration", nonce="2783a7947797f097b6b5ac2af9229dcd", qop="auth"
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 351
Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2020 12:33:57 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.32
```

Comment: Couple ideas, 1. Double check that your manifest has the right scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request) 2. Your `http://username:password@myServer` can you elaborate on what this is? Is this a localhost? Bear in mind that the request comes from Google's servers.

Comment: Expounding what @iansedano said, your manifest would be the most likely cause of the authorization issue.

similar questions were already asked in Stackoverflow and they point to the issue mentioned above.

This might be the most appropriate answer that can help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812174/unauthorized-401-error-while-execute-as-me

Comment: I have already checked the manifest and yes I have the external_request line. My script is already accessing some APIs with url fetch, so I think that scopes are good.
To be more precise on my situation, here is a complete description on what I try to do :
I have a bitcoin miner at home, which has a web server to monitor it and I want to put the data on a google sheet like every hour. The first step is to access the server through internet and for that I configured my router with NAT and I successfuly see my miner web page by using my public IP address but it is not working with googl script

Comment: And to add some other details, I think that the tricky part is about the authorization, because when I try to access to just the IP address, it asks me the login and password, so ok but how to give that credentials to the url fetch function ? I saw that we could embbed directly in the url with the form http://username:password@myServer instead of just http://myServer. I tried it on my phone and it works great. This form is appearently not supported by url fetch function, so I tried with the authorization header but I keeps getting error 401 as if my credentials are wrong.

Comment: Was your phone connected to the wifi of your local network? Can you test with a computer that is not in your local network? Have you made requests to your endpoint with other services like https://apitester.com/? Or cURL? Or a JS fetch running from your browser? Maybe the server you have set up blocks requests that don't come from users. What is the server you are using. Please, update your original question with all the info discussed in the comments, it keeps everything much cleaner.

Comment: When I tried on my phone, the wifi was disabled. I will test tomorrow at my parents house (just to be sure). I did not know about apitester.com, it seems useful. When I tried on it the direct link I get also the error 401, so maybe the issue is on the server side but I have no access to it. Is it even possible ? I mean, why my phone could have access and not apitester.com ? The web server running on the miner is a very basic web server running on a FPGA from Xilinx. I have some general logs on the machine but nothing really useful, I will put all the infos in the main question.

Comment: I added the logs and also the apitester.com response in main question

Comment: Maybe something to do with the [user agent header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) - its possible your server is auto configured to not accept requests from anything that is not a user/browser.

Comment: It works ! I tried to set the user agent but still error 401 and then I have the idea : hey, if there is some kind of filtering with headers, I will just copy all the parameters from a working connection with my browser, so I open my firefox console, copy out all the headers and it works.Now, by eliminating all the unnecessary ones, the right one was the authorization that does not use basic but another weird stuff that I did not know about. here is the format used : 
Digest username="root", realm="antMiner Configuration", nonce="XX", uri="/", response="XX", qop=auth, nc=00000001, cnonce="XX"

Comment: `Server: lighttpd/1.4.32` Please, please, please upgrade lighttpd to a recent release.  lighttpd 1.4.32 was released Nov 2012.  Latest lighttpd release as I write this is lighttpd 1.4.59.